Mapping variable to field filter in Metabase for native mongoDB query
I am trying to run a simple mongoDB query which returns the total count of documents in a collection with a variable which verdict_time which has been mapped to the corresponding field using field filter. The query is as follows:
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {{verdict_time}}
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "count"
  }
]

while running this query without passing any data to the variable it gives the appropriate results. But while passing any date as the filter I am getting the following error:
Command failed with error 16020 (Location16020): 'Expression $gte takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Expression $gte takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.", "code": 16020, "codeName": "Location16020"}

I want to understand if there is a problem in my approach or does metabase does not support vatibale for mongo queries.
Extra Deets:

MongoDB Version: 7.0.12
Metabase Open Source Version: v0.50.17

